# How to control the resulting sizes when splitting a window?

Tags: window-splitting

I often split my windows into two with `C-x 2`. The window in the bottom tends to be the SLIME's REPL or Magit and the one at the top is usually the common lisp file being edited.

I like to have more space for the file to be edited. Thus, every time, I keep doing:

(i) - `C-x 2`;
(ii) - Put the cursor on the window at the top (it is the default position);
(iii) - `C-x ^` enlarges the window. In order to do it multiple times, I use `C-u 7` to repeat it 7 times. Thus, I press `C-u 7 C-x ^`

Is there a way to automate this? Maybe adding a hook to my config files so that every time I press `C-X 2` then `C-u 7 C-x ^` happens?

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240192/emacs-slime-hard-code-vertical-split-ratio/10240378 (but we can't close questions as duplicates across sites).

Comment: A simple shortcut would be to create a keyboard macro that records the keys you're using now, then just use that keyboard macro. You can bind that to a key (even `C-x 2`).

Comment: you might want to have a look at the [golden-ratio](https://github.com/roman/golden-ratio.el) package which provides some more control over how windows are split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This old answer in stackoverflow pointed out by @phils really helped me.

The following code in my init file did the trick:

```lisp
(defun my-split-window-below (&optional arg)
  "Split the current window 70/30 rather than 50/50.
A single-digit prefix argument gives the top window arg*10%."
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((proportion (* (or arg 7) 0.1)))
    (split-window-below (round (* proportion (window-height))))))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x 2") 'my-split-window-below)
```